# identify stores not selling a product

Tags: sql, logic, business-logic

I have 2 tables city_products that contains all products in the city and product_list that contains all the products that exist in different cities.I want a list of products not available in each city.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Table 1:  **city_prd**

```
city    product
------  -------
city 1  p1
city 1  p3
city 1  p2
city 2  p1
city 2  p5
```

Table 2:  **pdt_list**

```
product
-------
p1
p2
p3
p4
p5
```

Desired output:

```
city    product
------  -------
city 1  p4
city 1  p5
city 2  p2
city 2  p3
city 2  p4
```

I know its something to do with a cross join but I am not getting the exact answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a variation of TheImpaler's answer, but it should work in all databases.  Use a `cross join` to generate all combinations of cities and products.  Then use `left join` (or a similar mechanism) to remove the ones that exist:

```
select c.city, p.product
from (select distinct city from city_prd) c cross join
     pdt_list p left join
     city_prd cp
     on c.city = cp.city and p.product = cp.product
where cp.city is null;
```

I am also guessing that you have a `cities` table of some sort.  You can use that instead:

```
select c.city, p.product
from cities c cross join
     pdt_list p left join
     city_prd cp
     on c.city = cp.city and p.product = cp.product
where cp.city is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention which database you are using, so I'll give you a generic SQL solution. You can adapt it to your specific RDBMS.

```
select
  c.city, p.product
from (
  select distinct city from city_prd
) c
cross join pdt_list p
except
select city, product from city_prd
order by c.city, p.product
```

Comment: Thanks! but should we do ```select distinct 
  c.city, p.product
from (
  select distinct city from city_prd
) c
cross join pdt_list p
except
select city, product from city_prd
order by c.city, p.product```

Comment: The extra `DISTINCT` you added won't produce any difference since the rows are distinct already. A SQL Fiddle could help visualizing it.